# Debian packages

Tags: formatting

I'm using Moodle and have LaTeX filter enabled, one of teacher will like to use `\fs{2}` command in LaTeX filter but it is not working. I'm guessing that it is because this library is not loaded. Do you know what Debian packages I have to load to server so that this command work?

Comment: What has Debian pacakges got to do with LaTeX? I don't see the connection at all.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Digging around, [Moodle suggests](http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/TeX_notation_filter) that one installs an up-to-date TeX distribution to provide the backend for the automatic LaTeX to GIF filter. So theoretically Debian's somewhat out-of-date TeXLive distribution may have something to do with the problem.

Comment: @Ivica: what is `\fs{2}` supposed to output? Almost certainly what you need to do is to follow the instructions in the link given in the above comment, and edit the configuration for the LaTeX preamble to load the appropriate LaTeX package. We may be able to help you track down the appropriate package, but you will need to tell us what the expected outcome is. The actual configuration of Moodle, however, is likely to be off-topic here.